# adding arbitrary information to recorder

Tags: openmdao

I'm running an optimization in OpenMDAO.  One of the components in the model writes a few files to a directory which is given a random name.  I track the progress of the optimization using a SqliteRecorder.  I would like to be able to correlate iterations in the sqlite database to the directories of each evaluation.

Is there a way to attach arbitrary information to a recorder - in this case, the directory name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest that you add a string typed output to the component and set it to the folder name. Then the recorder will capture it.